# Para que sirve ReactJs?

Tags: reactjs

No entiendo para que sirve ReactJs, he visto varios vídeos en algunos crean componentes de una forma un poco rara para mi pero no entiendo para qué es útil, en realidad crear componentes sería el equivalente a crear un elemento en jQuery hacer un clic y que guarde algo en base de datos sin que recargue el sitio es posible hacerlo desde hace mucho con jQuery y Ajax entonces de qué sirve?

¿Me explican?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suele ser una duda normal, stackoverflow en inglés debate un poco más sobre el tema

[react vs ajax](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35643991/difference-between-react-js-and-ajax)

Answer (score 1):

Siento decirte que tu pregunta se nota prejuiciosa, con desgana por aprender algo nuevo: Preguntar para qué sirve ReactJs porque ya tenemos jQuery para hacer cualquier cosa en javascript es como preguntar para qué sirve la programación orientada a objetos si ya teníamos la programación imperativa:

Frameworks y librerías como ReactJs, AngularJS, Angular, Aurelia, Ember... son frameworks que te permiten crear "Single Page Applications" (Aplicaciones en una sóla página) de un modo más eficiente que si usases los plugins de jQuery, tanto en tiempo de desarrollo como en velocidad de ejecución.

Comment: Es como preguntar para que queremos jQuery si ya tenemos javascript.

Comment: Es como preguntar para qué queremos a Messi si ya tenemos a Cristiano Ronaldo :P